# D - Read 4 byte size from socket

Tags: d

How can I read a uint from a connected socket directly without having to do any conversion.

Effectively, what is the D equivalent to `read(sock, &four_byte_var, 4)`.  I can't seem to convert a `uint` to anything that the D standard library `socket.receive(void[])` will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a slice that surrounds the variable:

```
uint n;
socket.receive((&n)[0..1]);
```

Note that this approach is endian-sensitive.

Comment: I'm new to D, what does ptrvar[0..1] give?

Comment: A dynamic array pointing to the variable with length 1 (no reallocation is done). D dynamic arrays consist of a length and a pointer to the array data. http://dlang.org/arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy with [`std.socketstream`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_socketstream.html):

```
auto stream = new SocketStream(socket);

uint foo;
stream.read(foo);
```

**Note:** the `std.stream` and `std.socketstream` modules will be replaced by a new interface (well, that might take a while).

Comment: The giant horrible all red warning at the top of the socketstream documentation scared me away from it.

Comment: That warning is a bad joke, `std.stream` and `std.socketstream` work perfectly fine and the replacement is not even in sight (from what I know). I think if we get a replacement, I'll still use these two stream-modules, because I am scared of the "new" `std.stream` (which will be range based).

Comment: `std.stream` is pretty bad, though. Data written on one machine will not be read properly on a machine with a different endianness or even pointer size (so x32 and x64 builds of your program are already incompatible). And if you try to mix reading text and binary data, you're gonna have a bad time.